# Laravel: combining results in nested foreach

Tags: jquery, laravel, join, foreach, nested

I'm trying to make a Task viewr based on Gantt Chart (http://thegrubbsian.github.io/jquery.ganttView/example/index.html)

So I have my Works table and Tasks Table (with work_id)

And I need to pass data to Gant Jquery as this:

```
var ganttData = [
{
    id: 1, name: "Feature 1", series: [
        { name: "Planned", start: new Date(2010,00,01), end: new Date(2010,00,03) },
        { name: "Actual", start: new Date(2010,00,02), end: new Date(2010,00,05), color: "#f0f0f0" }
    ]
},
{
    id: 2, name: "Feature 2", series: [
        { name: "Planned", start: new Date(2010,00,05), end: new Date(2010,00,20) },
        { name: "Actual", start: new Date(2010,00,06), end: new Date(2010,00,17), color: "#f0f0f0" },
        { name: "Projected", start: new Date(2010,00,06), end: new Date(2010,00,17), color: "#e0e0e0" }
    ]
}
```

In my Task Controller I have this:

```
$data['works'] = DB::table('works')
                 ->where('country', 'France')
                 ->get();
```

In my View, I have this:

```
$data = [];
foreach ($works as $work)
{
$data[] = [
    'id' => $work->id,
    'name' => $work->name,
    'series' => [
      HELP!!!
      'description' => ....,
      'startdate' => ....,
      'enddate' => ....,
    ]
];
};
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
```

And my problem is to add the sub foreach at SERIES. Here I need to add all the Tasks WHERE('work_id', $work->id)

How can I achieve this?

Many thanks!

Comment: You need a new php array for each item inside series. Not enough known about query results to provide more help

Comment: what is the relation defined between `Work` and `Task`? if it is a `one to many` then `foreach` the relation result (work->tasks;) and store it to an array and assign it to 'series'.

Comment: Yes, the relation is one to many and is defined in my model:

    public function tasks(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Tasks');
    }

But when I do: 

foreach ($work->task as $wt) {
            'name': $wt->id
          }

I get " FatalErrorException"

Is not the way?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figure it out the one to many relations.

My problem was that I'm using CRUDBOOSTER and return view in my controller was wrong...

Model:

```
public function tasks(){
 return $this->hasMany('App\Task');
}
```

Controller:

```
$works = Work::all();
return view('tasks.index')->with('works', $works);
```

in View I can use:

```
@foreach($works as $work)
 {{$work->id}}
 @foreach($work->tasks as $task)
  {{$task->id}}
 @endforeach
@endforeach
```

But I can´t make my array with 1 foreach inside another foreach:

```
<?php
$data = [];
foreach ($works as $work)
{
$data[] = [
    'id' => $work->id,
    'name' => $work->name,
    'series' => [
      foreach ($work->task as $task) {
          'name' => $task->description
        }
    ]
];
};
```

I get

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH), expecting ']'